# base64_decode error while using AzureStor and AzureRMR API

Tags: r, authentication, rstudio, azure-storage

I have a problem with using AzureStor API in RStudio.

First I login in Azure with:

```
az <- AzureRMR::create_azure_login()
```

I see a message in my browser that it was successful :

> Authenticated with Azure Active Directory. Please close this page and
> return to R.

After it I'm trying to upload a file to storage:

```
storage_account <- storage_endpoint("https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net", az)
container <- storage_container(storage_account, "container")
storage_upload(container, src = file_path, dest = folder_path)
```

After this I see this error:

> Warning: Error in openssl::base64_decode: check failed:
> (is.character(text))

I also see the same error while using `list_storage_files`, so I guess it's not `storage_upload` specific, and probably related to authentification somehow, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation [`here`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AzureStor/versions/3.7.0/topics/storage_endpoint), I believe you are getting this error because `storage_endpoint` method is expecting the 2nd argument as a base64 encoded string (which is account key) and you are passing something different.

Considering you are using Azure AD Auth, I believe you would need to acquire a token for the storage resource and pass that token to this method.

Not very familiar with R and this package, but I think your code would be something like this:

```
token <- AzureRMR::get_azure_token(resource="https://storage.azure.com", tenant="your-tenant-id", app="your-app-id")

storage_account <- storage_endpoint("https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net", token=token)

...rest of your code
```